# jQuery selector behavior differences between parent and popup windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, jquery-selectors, tampermonkey

To make my userscript work properly, I have implemented an ugly fix. To make a more straightforward and maintainable code, I need to better understand WHY the ugly fix works.  Some code for your consideration:

```
var win = window.open('','');
var txt = '<div id="myId"></div>';
win.document.write(txt);
win.document.close();
alert($('#myId').length);  // <=== displays a "0" ... WHY not a "1"??
```

The userscript running in the popup window itself provides the following:

```
alert('Running from the popup window '+$('#myId').length); // <=== displays a "1" ... why only here?
```

Why does `$('#myId')` not properly select the `div` when the userscript is run from the window from which the popup window was generated, but **does** select the `div` when a userscript is run from within the popup window itself?  Understanding the difference between these 2 situations is key to my being able to streamline my code (specifically, to be able to control everything from the parent window rather than requiring a separate userscript to run on the popup window).

Note: this question is a more focused question to [the one that I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765332/how-to-reference-div-in-popup-window-using-jquery-in-a-userscript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery (more specifically JS itself) will search elements only in your current window (as you know Window object is the top object in browser). Popup window is another window and has its own Window object. So there is two different scopes. In first case you search only in parent window and this window does not contain `#myId`, so jQuery finds nothing.

Comment: Hmm ... so is there a way to "change the scope" to the popup window while running the userscript from within the parent window, or are you saying that jQuery inherently can't change the scope?

Comment: You have a reference to the new window as `win`. So you can try something like this, `alert($(win.document).find('#myId').length)` will give you the length as 1.

Comment: Yes, `alert($(win.document).find('myId').length)` certainly works.  But the problem (which I didn't divulge in my question above, because I was trying to be succinct) is that the external js code that I am calling in my code expects the following format:  `$('#myId').jvenn`   When I try `$(win.document).find('myId').jvenn`, the jVenn code doesn't produce the lovely Venn diagrams in my popup window that should produce.   If there were a way, within the code that runs in the parent window, to somehow force  `$('#myId')` to equal `$(win.document).find('myId')` ... ???

Comment: I think it's not the case, you library expects jQuery object and it gets jQuery object, perhaps the problems is with something else. It hard to say without testing. Please verify in chrome tools that that diagram is not generated at all (perhaps it is generated but hidden) and also check console, maybe it shows some messages?